# Поиск по БД. Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysqlconnector

Необходимо осуществить поиск по базе данных, но после ввода названия книги выдает ошибку `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1`
Не могу понять в чем проблема. Спасибо за внимание!

**КОД:**

```py
sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE Name_of_the_book = %s"

print('Enter book name: ')
query = input()
cursor.execute(sql, query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
for x in result:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вторым аргументом метода `execute` должен быть кортеж, а не строка:

```py
cursor.execute(sql, (query,))
```